# Nested Document error on ES Tire Gem Ruby

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using the Tire gem still to work with a 0.9 ES database.

I've got a model that looks like this:

```
class Influencer
  include Tire::Model::Persistence
  include Tire::Model::DynamicPersistence

  document_type "influencer"

  # profiles 
  property :profiles,           :type     => 'nested', :class => [Profile], :default => []

end
```

I've also got a Profile class that looks like this.

```
class Profile
  include Tire::Model::Persistence
  include Tire::Model::DynamicPersistence

  document_type 'profile'

  property :id,                 :index    => :not_analyzed
  property :username,           :index    => :not_analyzed
  property :service,            :index    => 'keyword'
  property :url,                :index    => :not_analyzed
  property :score,              :type     => 'float', :index => :not_analyzed 
end
```

Note I removed many fields.

So, when I blow away the index and recreate it for influencers, I get an empty index. On the first write, it creates the mapping below:

```
{"influencer"=>
  {"properties"=>
    {"data"=>{"type"=>"object"},
     "demographics"=>{"type"=>"object"},
     "domain_names"=>{"type"=>"string"},
     "geographics"=>{"type"=>"object"},
     "host_names"=>{"type"=>"string"},
     "id"=>{"type"=>"string"},
     "income_message_numbers"=>{"type"=>"object"},
     "influencer_id"=>{"type"=>"string"},
     "keyword_scores"=>{"type"=>"object"},
     "keywords"=>{"type"=>"string"},
     "manual"=>{"type"=>"boolean"},
     "name"=>{"type"=>"string"},
     "notes"=>{"type"=>"object"},
     "profiles"=>
      {"properties"=>
        {"profile"=>
          {"properties"=>
            {"contributors_enabled"=>{"type"=>"boolean"},
             "default_profile"=>{"type"=>"boolean"},
             "description"=>{"type"=>"string"},
             "favourites_count"=>{"type"=>"long"},
             "followers_count"=>{"type"=>"long"},
             "friends_count"=>{"type"=>"long"},
             "id"=>{"type"=>"long"},
             "lang"=>{"type"=>"string"},
             "listed_count"=>{"type"=>"long"},
             "location"=>{"type"=>"string"},
             "name"=>{"type"=>"string"},
             "profile_image_url"=>{"type"=>"string"},
             "protected"=>{"type"=>"boolean"},
             "service"=>{"type"=>"string"},
             "statuses_count"=>{"type"=>"long"},
             "url"=>{"type"=>"string"},
             "username"=>{"type"=>"string"}}}}},
     "project_profiles"=>{"type"=>"object"},
     "project_statuses"=>{"type"=>"object"},
     "project_tags"=>{"type"=>"object"},
     "project_time_additions"=>{"type"=>"object"},
     "reachable_via"=>{"type"=>"string"},
     "share_counts"=>{"type"=>"object"},
     "source_ids"=>{"type"=>"string"},
     "sources"=>{"type"=>"string"}}}}
```

This is what the first hash that writes looks like. I THINK it looks correct, but I could very well be missing something.

```
{:name=>"DogeWire", :profiles=>[{"service"=>"twitter", "id"=>2465530645, "name"=>"DogeWire", "username"=>"DogeWire", "description"=>"Fast, safe, anonymous, wow", "location"=>"www.DogeWire.com", "protected"=>false, "followers_count"=>466, "friends_count"=>1990, "listed_count"=>2, "favourites_count"=>19, "statuses_count"=>8421, "lang"=>"en", "contributors_enabled"=>false, "profile_image_url"=>"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/460517818555846656/-0Ibxod4_normal.jpeg", "url"=>"http://twitter.com/DogeWire", "default_profile"=>true, "time_zone"=>nil}], :source_ids=>["twitter:2465530645"], :sources=>["twitter"], :keywords=>["altcoin"], :reachable_via=>["twitter"], :tags=>[], :host_names=>["www.lill.com"], :domain_names=>["lill.com"], :id=>"74uF9cNfW6dYEa27kSg5ww", :influencer_id=>"74uF9cNfW6dYEa27kSg5ww"}
```

And, lastly, the query looks like:

```
site_influencers = Influencer.search(:page => 1, :per_page => 10) do
    query do
        nested :path => 'profiles' do
          query do 
            boolean do
              must { match 'profiles.service',  'twitter' }
            end
          end 
        end
      end
    end
```

I'm not sure what i'm missing on this. This is a ruby app.. no Rails (but has ActiveRecord, etc).

Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe that subdocuments should support dynamic fields (besides the map). But, so far, I haven't sorted it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Update. Still no help. But, you must use the #create_elasticsearch_index not just the "create" method on the index, to get the mappings applied.